# How do you prevent Jasmine from timing out

Tags: jasmine

I'm using [Jasmine 2.0](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html). I register an event handler, and wait for it to fire so I can do my test:

```
$(document).on("pagechange", function() { expect(1).toBe(1); /* times out before it can evaluate this */ });
pageChanger.change("awesome page"); // is async, gets new page from server, fires pagechange when done
```

but Jasmine reports a failure after a few seconds. Is there a way to do something like:

```
jasmine.globalTimeout = 1000 * 60;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nm, i found it:

```
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1000 * 60;
```

[image]